# Converting a double sine function uint8 in Simulink - unexpected results

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'd like to know why does passing a sinusoidal signal (Amplitude : 1, Freq=1 1 Hz, sampling rate : 0.01 sec) through a uint8 produces a square wave. While I understand that it should be truncated at 255 if the value of the sinusoid is above 256, the sine wave's amplitude is only 1. Why is a square wave 0 to 255 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a function of how saturation occurs on integer overflow. (Note that the 255 in your square wave corresponds to the negative part of the sign wave, *not* the positive part, which is what your question seems to indicate you are thinking.  The positive part of the sine wave is rounding down to zero.)

As per the documentation for the [Data Type Conversion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/datatypeconversion.html) Block, and specifically the *Saturate on integer overflow* section, by default the negative part of the sine wave (which can't be represented exactly in a uint8) wraps to 255.  If you play with the way rounding occurs, and how saturation is handled, you should get a better feel for what's going on.